# display vertical lines and horizontal lines on plots

Tags: charts, highcharts, visualization

I'm using Highcharts to create scatter plots.

The problem is that the scatter plots seem to default to having background (i.e. not part of the data, just for scale) lines **either parallel to the x-axis, or to the y-axis, but not both at the same time.**

[Here's an example](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/scatter) that I used to get started making scatter plots.  Note the lines parallel to the x-axis.

How do I get a scatter plot with background lines in **both** axes?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The default values for the `gridLineWidth` is `1` for yAxis and `0` for xAxis, resulting in only the horizontal lines showing. What you need to do is to set the width to `1` for both x and y.

```
yAxis: {
    gridLineWidth: 1 // The default value, no need to change it
},

xAxis: {
    gridLineWidth: 1 // New value
},
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hPnFK/):

[image]